# Two equal dipoles separated by a non-grounded uncharged metallic plate

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a task where two equal dipoles are separated by a non-grounded, perfectly conducting thin plate. The dipoles are oriented along the plane direction and can be parallel or antiparallel oriented. I wonder what the force is between the plate and the dipoles and between the two dipoles and whether one can reach perfect force cancellation.
Thank you very much!
Alexey

Comment: This question should be restructured to be more general. This question should ask for conceptual clarification on how calculations of this sort are performed, such that the answer will be applicable to other similar problems rather than just this one specific problem.